# download.file returns error, when using special letters

Tags: r

I'm trying to download several zip files from a webpage. The problem is when, I try to use the `download.file` function it returns the following error message `cannot open URL` if I include the special danish letters æ, ø or å. I have the following piece of code

```r
link <- "http://web.econ.ku.dk/polit/studerende/eksamen/opgrv/filer/rv%20Øk%20B%20X2015S_takehome_answers.zip"

download.file(link, getwd())
```

Can someone explain to me, how I can use the `download.files()` with special letters.

Comment: Is it that `download.file(files_links[3], destfile = temp)` is overwriting the previous `download.file()` call, or do you get an error message?

Comment: I get the following message ```cannot open URL```. So it's no because of overwriting

Comment: Works fine for me just replacing `destfile = getwd()` (as implied) with any explicit file name. Doing so still causes an error for you?

Comment: So It does not throw an error when specifying the destfile argument, but I'm not able to unzip the file afterwards. If I download the zip manually through a webbrowser it works nicely. So the problem is that I can download the zip-file using R, but I cannot unzip the file

Comment: You need to properly URL encode that. %C3%98